# is there way to implement wildcard and implement 'once' action in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

1.I didn't find the way to implement 'once' listener like in firebase. i want to do it for improving performance because i don't need the data in realtime.

2. is there way to implement wildcard with firestore on get request?

Comment: If you have two different questions, it's a good idea to ask them separately so they can be answered independently of each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform a single `get()` to fetch data:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Filtering can be accomplished using a query:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");
```

I strongly recommend reading the associated documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: for my second question. i want to do wildcard.

Comment: Can you explain how that's different from doing a query?